# Icefaces ace:tree how do I the get the currently selected or expanded node

Tags: java, jsf, icefaces

I would to know how to reference currently selected and expanded nodes of an ace:tree. All pages load as expected and the ace:ajax tags fire the listeners when the root node is selected or expanded. The problem is that I can't find any documentation on how to reference the clicked node server side, either for expansion via +/- or selection.

```
<ace:ajax event="expand" listener="#{customerTreeBean.expandListener}" render="@all" execute="@all" />


public void expandListener(AjaxBehaviorEvent e){ 
     //How do I reference the expanded node
}

<ace:ajax event="select" listener="#{customerTreeBean.selectListener}" render="@all" execute="@all" />


public void selectListener(AjaxBehaviorEvent e){ 
     // How do I reference the expanded node
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use use stateMapTree

```
    List list = stateMapTree.getSelected();
    if ( list != null && list.size()>0 )
    {
        VersioneNodeImpl node = (VersioneNodeImpl)list.get(0);
        if ( node.getParent() == null ) 
            return;

        versione = node.getVersione();
        NavigationContr.getRataAction().select(versione);
        refreshProjects();
        refreshReport();
    }
```